# How to generate test reports using Junit+selenium+Eclipse?

Tags: java, selenium, ant, junit

I would like to know how to generate the test reports using junit+eclipse+selenium.
I m using java as the language.I tried something but i didn't do anything:
1) First generate an Ant build file for my project.
In the Export page select "Ant Buildfiles" it is under General. Then select a
project that contains your JUnit tests. The default JUnit output directory is
appropriately named "junit".
2) Next resolve dependencies by making sure that the junit.jar is added to Ant's
"Global Entries."
Window->Preferences->Ant->Runtime->Global Entries and Add External JARs...
Navigate to my "eclipse" directory (where eclipse is installed). It is under
*****"plugins" directory and presently the junit.jar is in a directory named
"org.junit_3.8.1".*****  <-I couldn't find this folder.

It would be great if some one could have given me the steps to generate test reports in eclipse +junit.

Answer (score 1):

Go through following link.[click here](http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/) contains step by step process. this works for me.

Comment: Thanks for answering.But,unfortunately, I tried this and it couldn't work.I couldn't find my JUnit folder.

Comment: start with new application & then build project with ant. are you doing these with the same project(i.e. previous ant build-ed project).

Comment: Yes, I did them in the same project.I am using JUnit4 version.

Comment: ok start with new application, This is working with the junit-4.10.jar in my environment.

Comment: http://testerinyou.blogspot.com/search/label/Reports                                                               I could do only 10 steps.Since I couldn't find the 'build.xml file',I didn't do 11. step,so Icouldn't create report.                                                              My JUnit version is 'org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030'.

Comment: i.e. means you can't do the ant build of project, do the first 4 steps as per order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extent report http://extentreports.com/. It's not hard to implement it in your project, the necessary code you can find in their examples.